# Create a weighted adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, weighted

I have a `csv` file structured in the following way:

```
id  Author                Contribution  Coauthors
1   Anders B.             0.111111111   9
1   Blatt I.              0.111111111   9
1   Chung S.S.            0.111111111   9
1   Clark A.M.            0.111111111   9
1   Fakhoury T.A.             0.111111111   9
1   Halvorsen M.B.            0.111111111   9
1   Laine D.              0.111111111   9
1   Lawson B.             0.111111111   9
1   Nagaraddi V.              0.111111111   9
1   Hogan R.E.            0.111111111   9
2   Isaksson A.           0.5           2
2   Kaulich F.            0.5           2
2   Foster-McGregor N.    0.5           2
3   Van Houte M.              0         0
4   van de Meerendonk A.      1         1
4   Koning P.             1         1
```

where `id` = paper unique identifier.

I would like to create in R a weighted adjacency matrix where the links between each couple of authors are weighted in the following way:

```
Weight i,j = SUM for all id of [link i,j (0,1) / (Number coauthors of each id -1)]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to understand the weight function. What does `link` mean in that case? Can you give a short example of weighted matrix?

Comment: I do a similar stuff and use the Python package `networkx` to do this.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear!The first column identifies the paper, the second colum identifies the number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R iGraph: How to get weighted adjacency matrix from a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423635/r-igraph-how-to-get-weighted-adjacency-matrix-from-a-graph)