# Given the data, how can I create a matrix similar to an adjacency matrix in R?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

My trial data is given as follows:

```
testdata = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,10,11,12,13,
14,15,16,17,28,30,25,40,50,47,62,23),ncol=3,byrow=F)
colnames(testdata)=c("index","contact","age")

testdata
#>      index contact age
#> [1,]     1      10  28
#> [2,]     1      11  30
#> [3,]     1      12  25
#> [4,]     2      13  40
#> [5,]     2      14  50
#> [6,]     3      15  47
#> [7,]     3      16  62
#> [8,]     3      17  23
```

From the given data, I want create a matrix similar to an adjacency matrix as follows.

```
adjmat = matrix(c(0,0,0,28,30,25,rep(0,11),40,50,
rep(0,11),47,62,23,28, rep(0,10),30,rep(0,10),25, rep(0,11), 40, rep(0,10),50, 
rep(0,11),47, rep(0,10), 62,rep(0,10), 23, rep(0,8)),ncol=11,byrow=T,     
dimnames = list(c("1", "2","3","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"),
c("1","2","3","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17")))
```

That means in matrix form it will be as follows:

```
adjmat
#>     1  2  3 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
#> 1   0  0  0 28 30 25  0  0  0  0  0
#> 2   0  0  0  0  0  0 40 45  0  0  0
#> 3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 47 62 23
#> 10 28  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 11 30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 12 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 13  0 40  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 14  0 50  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 15  0  0 47  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 16  0  0 62  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 17  0  0 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

How can I do that? I tried with the following for 
loop, but it was not successful as expected.

```
index=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
   contact=c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
   age=c(28,30,25,40,50,47,62,23)
   row=c(1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
   col=c(1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
   x=matrix(, nrow=11, ncol=11)

 for (i in 1:length(row)){
     for (j in 1:length(col)){
       for (k in 1:length(index)){
          for (m in 1:length(contact)){
   if(index[k]==row[i] & contact[m]==col[j]) {x[i,j]<- age[k]}
          else {x[i,j]<- 0}   
   print(x)   
     }}}}
```

Comment: How did you know the code you wrote is not working? It gives an error (please share the error message) or the result doesn't match the expectation? (please share the result)

Comment: Dear David,
Thanks for your reply. I think some other friends already showed the way to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I've had that exact problem a few weeks back and ended up writing and adding a function for exactly that in the `networkR` package.

The `adjacency` function takes three vectors representing `from`, `to`, and `weight` which correspond to your three columns. The argument `directed=FALSE` is set to make the output symmetric.

```
library(networkR)
testdata = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,10,11,12,13,
                    14,15,16,17,28,30,25,40,50,47,62,23),ncol=3,byrow=F)

result <- adjacency(from=testdata[,1], 
                    to=testdata[,2], 
                    weight=testdata[,3], directed=FALSE)

result
```

which returns a sparse matrix with the following output.

```
11 x 11 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"

 [1,]  .  .  . 28 30 25  .  .  .  .  .
 [2,]  .  .  .  .  .  . 40 50  .  .  .
 [3,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 47 62 23
 [4,] 28  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [5,] 30  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [6,] 25  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [7,]  . 40  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [8,]  . 50  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [9,]  .  . 47  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
[10,]  .  . 62  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
[11,]  .  . 23  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: Many thanks ekstroem! This is one of the best solutions.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer, so that others visiting this question later can more easily access it, and to give back to ekstroem :)

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution will be something like:

```
> x<-unique(sort(testdata[,1:2]))
> m=matrix(0,length(x),length(x),dimnames = list(x,x))
> m[cbind(testdata[,1],which(x%in%testdata[,2]))]=testdata[,3]
> m[lower.tri(m)]=t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
> m
    1  2  3 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
1   0  0  0 28 30 25  0  0  0  0  0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0 40 50  0  0  0
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 47 62 23
10 28  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11 30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13  0 40  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14  0 50  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15  0  0 47  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16  0  0 62  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
17  0  0 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: My friend, Onyambu, thanks very much for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you you are willing to use the [igraph](/questions/tagged/igraph) package [it can be done relatively easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423636/1305688),

```
# install.packages(c("igraph"), dependencies = T)
require(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(testdata, directed=F, vertices=NULL)
m <- as_adjacency_matrix(g, attr = "age", sparse = F)
identical(m, adjmat)
#> [1] TRUE
m
#>     1  2  3 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
#> 1   0  0  0 28 30 25  0  0  0  0  0
#> 2   0  0  0  0  0  0 40 50  0  0  0
#> 3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 47 62 23
#> 10 28  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 11 30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 12 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 13  0 40  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 14  0 50  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 15  0  0 47  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 16  0  0 62  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 17  0  0 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Dear Eric, Many thanks for one of the best solutions. I know how to use igraph package, but could not find a way to implement this way! thanks for kind help again.

Comment: Glad it was useful. Don't forget to mark your preferred answer  as _accept_. [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The function @ekstroem developed is probably more flexible, but you do not need any loops to create the matrix:

```
testdata <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,10,11,12,13,
    14,15,16,17,28,30,25,40,50,47,62,23), ncol=3, 
    byrow=FALSE)
colnames(testdata)=c("index","contact","age")

rc <- unique(c(testdata[, 1:2]))
adjmat <- matrix(0, length(rc), length(rc), dimnames=list(rc, rc))
idx1 <- match(testdata[, 1], rc)
idx2 <- match(testdata[, 2], rc)
adjmat[cbind(idx1, idx2)] <- testdata[, 3]
adjmat[cbind(idx2, idx1)] <- testdata[, 3]
adjmat
```

Gives you the following result:

```
    1  2  3 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
1   0  0  0 28 30 25  0  0  0  0  0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0 40 50  0  0  0
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 47 62 23
10 28  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11 30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12 25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13  0 40  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14  0 50  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15  0  0 47  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16  0  0 62  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
17  0  0 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Just noticed that @Onyambu provided the same solution before I finished this.

Comment: Thank you, dcarlson, my friend for the solution.